# I am not getting why I am getting a Memory Limit Exceeded "Error" in the SnapShot Array Question

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, constructor, out-of-memory

Question  :  [Snapshot  Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/snapshot-array/)

```
class SnapshotArray 
{
 vector<int> m; 
 map<int, vector<int>> m1;
 int count=0;

    public:
    SnapshotArray(int length) : m(length)
    {
     for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
         m[i]=0;
    }
    
    void set(int index, int val) 
    {
     m[index]=val;    
    }
    
    int snap() 
    {
        count++;
        int snap_id = count - 1;
        m1[snap_id] = m;
        return snap_id;
    }
    
    int get(int index, int snap_id) 
    {
      return m1[snap_id][index];
    }
 };
```

I have no idea why I am getting the Memory Limit Exceeded Error.
Please help correct the error.

Also if I change the constructor to :

```
SnapshotArray(int length) {
   for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
       m[i]=0;
   }
```

The error I am getting is :

````
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9```
````

Comment: If you remove `m(length)` from the constructor initializer list the vector remains empty and `m[i]=0;` accesses it out of bounds.

Comment: How much memory are you trying to allocate? The problem says a length of up to 50000 and up to 50000 calls of `snap`. That's 50000 vectors of 50000 ints of ints, or 2.5 billion ints, which is a lot.